# Parse.com cloud calls count as query?

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am uisng parse.com cloud code and calling this method -

```
 [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"getTime" withParameters:@{} block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error)
```

this calls on the cloud code for -

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getTime", function(request, response) {
                   response.success(new Date().getTime().toString());
                   });
```

My question - doe's this call cost money? i mean is that count for a query/call that need to be payed for? (because you have 30 queries or calls per second and than you start paying for every other call)

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not true, you're not charged for extra calls.

In simple words if you buy a machine worth $100 which packs 40 packets in one second and you piled 400 packs in front of it. Then it will take 10 seconds to pack all the packets. The manufacturing company will not charge you extra, just because you gave the machine 400 packs in just one second.

If your account is free then you are allowed only 30 calls/sec, which mean if you have 40 calls in one second then the reset 10 will be entertained in next second which will cause delay in the response.

And if your have pricing plan $100 per month then you are allowed 40calls/sec. Which mean if you have 50calls/sec, only 40 will be entertained in first second and the rest 10 will be entertained in the next second. You won't be charged for extra calls per second.

***The whole pricing plan depends upon  response time that you want to compromise.*** The more users the less response time. Go check the pricing plans and see how they are increasing the background jobs for your plan and the number of request.

You can check [pricing plan here](https://parse.com/plans)

Although the kind of payment you were talking about is true for the push notifications. In this case they will charge you

> $0.05/1000 extra recipients

Comment: Thanks, Great explanation about the way it works but the question remains , does this - [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground: - count as one of this 30 per second?

Comment: Great explanation, I didnt have that clear, @ozd when calling `PFQuery` or `PFCloud` counts as a request cause you are calling the server, debug with your stadistics and check it out yourself.

Comment: @ozd Yes it will cause you one call, as it is requesting the parse server.